# Largest product in a series (projecteuler)

Tags: python

The ProjectEuler's [problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) states:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
>   greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> ```
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
> 96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
> 85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
> 12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
> 66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
> 62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
> 30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
> 70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
> 65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
> 52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
> 53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
> 83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
> 82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
> 16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
> 17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
> 24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
> 07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
> 84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
> 05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
> 71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
> ```
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

I know that there are various solutions for this excercise available, but I don't want to spoil myself. I have a certain algorithm in mind: calculating the product of the first thirteen digits d_1, ..., d_13, then move one to the right and calculate the product of d_2, ..., d_14, and if this product is greater then the product before, this is supposed to be our new greatest product and so on, until we reach the end of the digits. But I don't see how I would go about something like this in Python. Naive as I am, I tried to copy the whole 1000 digit number, but yeah, I guess this isn't what I am supposed to do here.

But how am I able to work with this number then?

Comment: Read the number as a string and slice the string to get the part you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read in the number as a string you can use Python's implicit [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

```
num = (
    "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
    "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
    "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
    ...
)
```

Once you have the string, you can read the digits in chunks of the required length and calculate the product. For that, the [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function may be useful:

```
from functools import reduce

series_len = 13
max_product = 0

for i in range(len(num) - series_len):
    digits = num[i:i+series_len]
    product = reduce(lambda x, y: x*int(y), digits, 1)

    if product > max_product:
        max_product = product
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I read in the number without receiving an error message? " " " .... " " " is not working, for example. It gives ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

Comment: Use the fact that Python concatenates adjacent strings (see the update).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Although I really don't see how I deserve the downvotes.